# Zeppelin Pyspark on HDP 2.3 giving error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to configure zeppelin to work with HDP 2.3 (Spark 1.3). I have successfully installed zeppelin via Ambari and the zeppelin service is running.

But when I am trying to run any `%pyspark` command I am getting the below error.

I read few blogs but seems like there is some issue with jar being compiled on Java 6 and Java 7 that are being shared between Python and Spark.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, sandbox.hortonworks.com): org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Error from python worker:
  /usr/bin/python: No module named pyspark
PYTHONPATH was:
  /opt/incubator-zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark-0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)

(<class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>, Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.\n', JavaObject id=o68), <traceback object at 0x2618bd8>)
Took 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just setup a fresh HDP 2.3 setup (2.3.0.0-2557) on Centos 6.5 using Ambari 2.1 and installed zeppelin using Ambari zeppelin service (using default configs). Pyspark seems to work fine for me.

Based on your error it sounds like PYTHONPATH is not getting set to the correct value:

```
PYTHONPATH was:
  /opt/incubator-zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark-0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

In zeppelin can you enter the below in a cell and run it and provide the output?

```
System.getenv().get("MASTER")
System.getenv().get("SPARK_YARN_JAR")
System.getenv().get("HADOOP_CONF_DIR")
System.getenv().get("JAVA_HOME")
System.getenv().get("SPARK_HOME")
System.getenv().get("PYSPARK_PYTHON")
System.getenv().get("PYTHONPATH")
System.getenv().get("ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS")
```

Here is the output on my setup:

```
res41: String = yarn-client
res42: String = hdfs:///apps/zeppelin/zeppelin-spark-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
res43: String = /etc/hadoop/conf
res44: String = /usr/java/default
res45: String = /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/
res46: String = null
res47: String = /usr/hdp/current/spark-client//python:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client//python/lib/pyspark.zip:/usr/hdp/current/spark-client//python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip
res48: String = -Dhdp.version=2.3.0.0-2557 -Dspark.executor.memory=512m -Dspark.yarn.queue=default
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you check in your zeppelin-env.sh if you have the below line?

```
export PYTHONPATH=${SPARK_HOME}/python
```

If missing, this can be added via Ambari under Zeppelin > Configs > Advanced zeppelin-env > zeppelin-env template

Although, if you installed using the latest version of [Ambari service for zeppelin](https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/ambari-zeppelin-service) then it should have done this for you:
https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/ambari-zeppelin-service/blob/master/configuration/zeppelin-env.xml#L63

Comment: Yes I have this variable set. Like you said it is automatically taken care while installing. Thanks